# Process an HTML form with a bash script?

Tags: html, bash, forms, shell

I want to make an HTML form to input variables into a bash script and then run it, which sounds like a simple concept but I haven't found any way to do it. [The bash script makes directories, adds lines to files... If that is important]

- How would I do this?
- Is there something I should read on this?

`form action="script.sh"` ?

- Then how would I do this equivalent to PHP?

`$_POST["INPUT"]`

Thanks for reading and I am grateful for any comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost surely a bad idea. You shouldn't be using `bash` to write CGI (or any other non trivial) scripts. You should probably not be using CGI at all.

However, if you *do* want to go ahead with this, consider using http://bashlib.sourceforge.net/